# How to write a query in mongo DB where key is present inside an object of objects at multiple positions?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Sample Data :

```
{
"identifier": "1",
"family": "accessories",
"parent": null,
"groups": [],
"categories": [
   "A",
   "B",
   "C"
],
"enabled": true,
"value": {
            "name": [
                {
                    "locale": null,
                    "scope": null,
                    "data": "TV"
                }
            ],
            "customText": [
                {
                    "locale": "de_DE",
                    "scope": "ecommerce",
                    "data": "ABC"
                },
                {
                    "locale": "en_US",
                    "scope": "ecommerce",
                    "data": "BCD"
                },
                {
                    "locale": "fr_FR",
                    "scope": "ecommerce",
                    "data": "ASD"
                }
            ],
            "newAttribute": [
                {
                    "locale": "de_DE",
                    "scope": null,
                    "data": "asdasd"
                },
                {
                    "locale": "en_US",
                    "scope": null,
                    "data": "asd"
                },
                {
                    "locale": "fr_FR",
                    "scope": null,
                    "data": "awd"
                }
            ],
            "release_date": [
                {
                    "locale": null,
                    "scope": "ecommerce",
                    "data": "2012-03-29T00:00:00+00:00"
                }
            ],
            "targetLocales": [
                {
                    "locale": null,
                    "scope": null,
                    "data": [
                        "fr_FR"
                    ]
                }
            ]
}
}
```

This is my sample data where I have multiple documents with value attribute. And I want to find all those results where locale = "de_DE". But I am not able to come up with a query. I am very new to this mongoDB and all I could think of is :

```
collection.find( $elemMatch : { value.name.locale : "de_DE" }, $elemMatch : { value.customText.locale : "de_DE" }, ...)
```

which is clearly not an optimised way. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [$or-clausel](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) and pass in all the expressions you want to match.

```
const localName = "de_DE";

YourCollection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      "value.name.locale": localName 
    },
    {
      "value.customText.locale": localName 
    },
    {
      "value.newAttribute.locale": localName 
    },
   // repeat for the rest of the fields
  ]
});
```

Here's an example on mongoplayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/5YAJQvWjMJq

If you only want to match a document if all of above fields contain `"de_DE"` you can simply exchange `$or` for `$and`.